# Obtaining list of all addresses having sent money to a specific adress inside a Solidity contract

Tags: contract-design

For a certain contract A to execute and transfer specific amounts to other sub-contracts, I need a way to determine all the contributors amounts and addresses and make certain computations before configuring the details and amounts in the sub-contracts. Because of this, off-chain inspection of the blockchain will not suffice

What alternatives are there for designing this?

Comment: I don't think this information is available to a contract. Perhaps the smart contract can instead keep track of the contributions as they come in, via a `payable` function that tracks who deposited what.